# JtextField is not displaying full text

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a code that generates tag by pressing button ...like you type some random word then it generates a list of tags, here's the code

```
JButton tagGen = new JButton("GENERATE");
        tagGen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String copyTag;
                String title = textField.getText();
                String[] keywords = {"Google", "Yahoo", "Bing", "DuckDuckGo"};

            for(int i=0; i<keywords.length; i++) {
                copyTag = (title.replaceAll("Search Engine|search |is |Is","") 
                    + keywords[i]+", ");
                textTag.setText(copyTag);
            }
        }
```

So the problem is i'm not getting the full tags like this...

**random text Google, random text Yahoo, random text Bing, random text DuckDuckGo,**

instead getting the only last tag...

**random text DuckDuckGo,**

what i'm doing wrong? i'm using **setText** method but still it's not printing full text

i tried to search the fix of this problem but couldn't find any solution

Comment: Not sure what you try to accomplish. And not sure why do you tag your question as JavaFX while it seems to be only swing... Put the `textTag.setText(copyTag);` out of the `for` loop, just after. And append the text in the `copyTag` variable instead of reassigning it each time by doing this for example  `copyTag ` **+** `= (title.replaceAll("Search Engine|search |is |Is","") + keywords[i]+", ");`

Comment: @Pagbo thanks it fixed the problem but it's taking too much processing time when working with around 500+ tags any idea to reduce the time? it's actually taking around 25-30 second....

Comment: @kleopatra i already demonstrated what i can, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should make a performance analysis to see which instruction is too long, but you could begin by appending your tags into a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String`. And above at all, if the data process is expected to be long, **do not execute it in the graphic thread** (no matter if it is the EDT or the JavaFX thread) or you will get freeze.

Comment: read the referenced help page and provide the example as suggested ... anyway, what does this have to do with fx, the snippet is for JButton aka Swing?

Comment: @Pagbo yeah it's a java swing program **GUI** based i just have long keywords around **500+**  and it's taking time in **GUI** but not in CLI, how can i reduce the time?

Comment: @kleopatra okay thanks i just fixed the tag

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a JextField for this.

Instead use a `JTextArea` then in your loop you can use:

```
//textTag.setText(copyTag);
textArea.append(copyTag);
```